# FlashDevelop + Haxe -- use an embedded font

Tags: fonts, embedding, flashdevelop, haxe

I've added my TTF file to my Haxe project, and it appears to be embedded into the swf, but i have no clue how to get any of my TextFields to use it. How can i do that?

Update: I have a project set up as the same (for the purposes of this question) as [this tutorial](http://xlandersoftware.com/tutorial/how-to-embed-a-font-and-display-text-using-flashdevelop-and-haxe), and my font is not showing up (while theirs is). It seems to have to do with the issue outlined in [this forum thread](http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=6639&hilit=use+embedded+font), but since i have no access to the AS3 code generated, i can't tell the compiler to issue an embed tag with that flag set. What can i do, if anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be that I set the `text` var of the `TextField` before having it load the font. Whoops!